# Installing MSI vb.net with MsiSetExternalUI

Tags: progress-bar, windows-installer, vb.net-2010

I am trying to create an vb.net project which will call multiple msi’s to install.

I have been able to do this using

```
Program.StartInfo.FileName = "C:Windows\System32\msiexec.exe"
Program.StartInfo.Arguments = "/i  MsiName.msi /qb”
Program.Start()
Program.WaitForExit()
```

This works but I would like to be able to use the form to display a progress bar that relates to the progress of the install which I think uses MsiSetExternalUI and be able to pass exit codes to the exe.

I’m not sure how to call the msi’s this way. Can anybody help with a code to call one msi and pass this information so I can display it on a form?

Thank you for your help.

***Update***

I can find some C++ examples and coding, but unfortunately I am relatively new to scripting, so I do not know how to convert C++ to VB.net so any help in coding of this process would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the problem I am having is that I do not know how to call the function or the syntax to use, I have had a look about and not been able to find anything as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Windows Installer XML's (Wix) Deployment Tools Framework (DTF) MSI interop library (Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll )   It has all the pieces needed to invoke an installation and provide an external UI handler to receive the ProgressBar update messages that you can then route to your VB.Net UI.

See the following topic and subtopics for more information:

[Monitoring an Installation Using MsiSetExternalUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The examples are in C++ using MSI Win32 functions and the DTF interop library encapsulates all of this with classes.  The DTF help file tells you which classes and methods map to which Win32 functions.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the problem I am having is that I do not know how to call the function or the syntax to use, I have had a look about and not been able to find anything as of yet.